# Referencing Fields from an Externally Described File

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I am brand new to RPG programming.

```
F/SPACE 2                                                      
FVSPerf  IF   E           K Disk    Prefix(s)               
FVhipp  O    E              Printer Prefix(rp) OfLInd(*IN90)
```

With the code above I am trying to define an external table file and prefix it. However when I try to set any fields from the Vhipp print file, like so:

```
Z-ADD     0             rpRpTot
```

I get a compile error stating: the name or indicator is not defined. This happens with all fields from Vhipp.

Am I missing something obvious here? My understanding of RPG is once you define an external files you can make reference to its fields, am I defining the file incorrectly?

Comment: Excellent question, I'm hoping to see the answer as well.

Comment: What version of the OS are you on? Matters for coding style and dev environment recomendations.

Comment: Do you have any other compile errors? It looks as if the compiler might not be seeing your file, or may be seeing a version in a different library that doesn't have that field.  You are correct that RPG will let you reference all fields in an externally described file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I did not have key fields defined in working storage. Those keyfields are the used to populate Venshipp fields but since they were blank/null the table fields came back as being undefined.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. It doesn't seem to relate to the Z-ADD statement at all, so it shouldn't relate to the error in your question. Also, you probably shouldn't be using a Z-ADD instruction in the first place. Just code { **rptRptTot = 0 ;** }.

Answer (score 1):

We'd need to see the DDS for the printer file.   A compile listing possibly as well.

I just did a quick test and things worked fine:

From the DDS:

```
A          R DETAIL8                                       
A                                      SPACEB(1)           
A            TESTDATA     100         1
```

The File Definition:

```
FTEST4PT   O    E             PRINTER INFDS(OPNFBK) PREFIX(rpt)
```

From the compile listing:

```
O                       RPTTESTDATA        100A CHAR      100 (TESTDATA)
```

So as you can see, the prefix was put on the field from the externally described Printer file.